# Extract data from range with both empty and filled data

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

My problem is i need the objects from  certain range date . In that i am having filled data for some dates and for some dates there is no data. For one date one form ,if user fill the form and submit then it will store for that date

```
 rows = Grades.objects.filter(
    user_ql__created_at__range=(from_date, to_date).order_by('-user_ql__created_at').values()
```

when I print length of rows I got only 5 objects . Actually the date range is 7 days I am getting only 5 dates object because in that date range only 5 date are filled remaining 2 dates are not filled 
i need to show that all the objects of rows which are filled  not filled dates also

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to show dates that are in that range, **and also** show the ones that are not defined (empty)? Is that right?

Comment: Not the date range  I want to show the objects of all the with in the date range but in that range some are filled with some data and other dates not filled when i print it showing the only filled dates data